# syntax error: operand expected (error token is " ")

Tags: bash, unix

```
syntax error: operand expected (error token is " ")
```

I'm getting this syntax error with my current code:

```
log= who | grep $1 | cut -c 30-31,33-34
echo $log

time= date | cut -c 12-13,15-16
echo $time

on=$(($time - $log))
echo $on
```

If I remember correctly, " " stands for null. Why am I getting this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the space which was just after to `=` symbol and put the command inside `$()`, so that it would parse.

```
log=$(who | grep $1 | cut -c 30-31,33-34)
```

And,

```
time=$(date | cut -c 12-13,15-16)
```